# How to edit an opencart footer?

Tags: php, opencart

I'm presuming I have to edit the footer through mysql, I haven't done this website, a colleague who has decided not to come back into work has put this together http://tandgwebdesign.co.uk/ashleafarmshop.co.uk/ and it's using the Journal 2 theme, however, usually I would edit the footer through the footer.tpl, or even in the admin panel, however I can't fathom a way of editing the "FREE DELIVERY ON ALL ORDERS OVER £80" and the few lines of text below.

Could anyone help me out and tell me how to edit this through MySQL? It's an OpenCart website, or is there any easier way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

The footer is stored in a file called `footer.tpl` in the following folder:

```
catalog/view/theme/YOUR_THEME_NAME/template/common/footer.tpl
```

Check the footer's `<h1>` tag and see if you can edit the text there. If there's only a variable there, then I guess it stored in a language file (`catalog/language/YOUR_LANGUAGE/common/footer.php`).