# Footer don't change Opencart

Tags: php, html, task-parallel-library, opencart, footer

I am trying to edit the footer of my store. But nothing seems to happen. I have to add one more div in the content but it doesn't display on the store, neither the css.

```
<div class="payment col-sm-12">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <p> <?php echo $text_payment; ?> </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
footer .payment {
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
}
```

Has anyone a clue?

Comment: The footer's content is located in template's layout. You can simply edit it. You can't find the template's layout or when you edit it nothing happens? Please be more specific

Comment: @bad_boy when i edit it nothing happens

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25865186/1208233

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller file : catalog/controller/common/footer.php
View File : catalog/view/theme/[ default/your theme ]/template/common/footer.tpl

Please confirm that you are making changes on these files.

Also if you are using Opencart 2.x

Go to admin > Extensions > Modifications > click on the Refresh button to rebuild modifications. Please don't edit files on modifications folder directly. The changes will be lost when you rebuild modifications on admin.

Comment: yeah, i was change the right files... but then i start to edit system/modification/catalog/view/theme/template/common/footer.tpl and display in my store. do you know why?

Comment: When you edit the original file, you should go to admin > Extensions > Modifications > click on the Refresh button to rebuild modifications.
Please don't edit files on modifications folder directly. The changes will be lost when you rebuild modifications on admin.

Comment: hi, i didnt see the option to change the footer (image)

Comment: No, what i said was, just change the footer image url in the View File : catalog/view/theme/[ default/your theme ]/template/common/footer.tpl and goto admin > Extensions > Modifications > click on the Refresh button (an icaon above) to rebuild modifications.